# Using promises with jquery UI

Tags: jquery, promise

I'm struggling with promises. I have created this function to ask the user for a response before proceeding:

```
function dialogConfirm(msg, title) {
  promises = [];
  $('#dialog_yesno').html(msg).dialog({
    modal: true,
    title: title,
    buttons: {
      'Yes': function() {
        promises.push(true);
        $(this).dialog("close");
      },
      'No': function() {
         promises.push(false);
         $(this).dialog("close");
       }
    }
  });
  return promises;
}
```

called like this:

```
var msg = 'The record has been changed [etc] ...';
dialogConfirm(msg, 'Query').then(function(retVal) {
  if(retVal) {
    $('#save').trigger('click');
  }
});
```

The code drops through the UI dialog without waiting for a user response.

How should one write this?

Comment: Don't see how that isn't throwing an error since there is no `thenable` object returned from the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `true` which you push in to the `promises` array isn't an async operation, hence the logic continues synchronously.

I assume from the context of the question that you want to return a promise from `dialog()` which gets resolved when a button is clicked? If so you need to manually create the `Promise` and resolve it within the click handlers, like this:

```js
function dialogConfirm(msg, title) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $('#dialog_yesno').html(msg).dialog({
      modal: true,
      title: title,
      buttons: {
        'Yes': function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
          resolve();
        },
        'No': function() {
          $(this).dialog("close");
          reject();
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

dialogConfirm(msg, 'Query').then(function() {
  // 'yes' was clicked...
  $('#save').trigger('click');
}).catch(function() {
  // 'no' was clicked...
});
```

Comment: Thank you, that's very helpful of you. Now I must learn why it works!

Comment: No problem, glad to help. If you want to research Promises a good place to start is [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)